# Fragment showing in the background of previous fragment view

Tags: android, android-fragments

I implemented a fragment with Coverflow, and adding another fragment over it, but next fragment is visible in the background of the Coverflow. Means Coverflow is visible after another fragment get visible on to it. Please suggest any solution regarding the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should remove or hide the last fragment using FragmentTransaction.

Comment: Hi Jared, Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't want to remove or hide any fragment.

Comment: ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, "your fragment name");